# Alexa has trouble accessing my skill

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit

### Cross-posted on [Amazon Developer Forums](https://forums.developer.amazon.com/questions/33051/alexa-has-trouble-accessing-my-skill.html)

When developing one of my skills, I noticed that in the service simulator, invoking the skill with an intent `Welcome` — which should dispatch to my `get_welcome_response()` function — fails unless it thinks that this is not a new session. This is reflected back when testing with the actual Echo device when I simply invoke the skill without a specific intent — which again, should default to my `get_welcome_response()` function — and I get Alexa telling me that it is having trouble accessing that particular skill. Here is what the `get_welcome_response()` function for this skill looks like:

```
def get_welcome_response():

session_attributes = {}
card_title = "Welcome"
speech_output = "Welcome to Bravo Lima." \
        "Please state username and password"
# If the user either does not reply to the welcome message or says something
# that is not understood, they will be prompted again with this text.
reprompt_text = "Unable to authenticate." \
        "Please repeat username and password"
should_end_session = False
return build_response(session_attributes, build_speechlet_response(
    card_title, speech_output, reprompt_text, should_end_session))
```

However, since the whole of this skill itself is quite complicated, I wrote a new one that is very simple to try and see if I could simply invoke this skill. The skill has one function, which is the `get_welcome_response()`:

```
def get_welcome_response():

session_attributes = {}
card_title = "Welcome"
speech_output = "Hello. " \
                "Good morning, " \
                "is their coffee in that nebula?"
should_end_session = True
return build_response(session_attributes, build_speechlet_response(
    card_title, speech_output, None, should_end_session))
```

If this skill is invoked without an intent, it goes here. I've also defined it as an intent to test in the service simulator, and it works regardless or whether or not it considers this a new session. Alexa is able to recognize this skill when invoked using the Echo and responds accordingly.

The way the AWS lambda server handles both the more complicated skill I was working with before and this one is barely any different. The only two differences between either `get_welcome_response()` function, is:

1. that the former requires a `should_end_session = False` because it needs to pass the `session_attributes` variable around to other functions for various other intents in the skill to work properly.
2. the latter has no reprompt text

Both of these skills are created using Amazon's `MyColorIs` template, so the functions at the beginning of the code — like the `lambda_handler`, `on_session_started`, `on_launch` etc functions are structurally the same.

Some added information to rule out possible issues (and to show that this isn't a duplicated question):

1. My Echo is registered with the same account as my developer account on AWS
2. I entered the correct ARN code as the endpoint in the developer console for each skill
3. Everything on the lambda server side executes properly
4. I have asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38108542/utterances-to-test-lambda-function-not-working-but-lambda-function-itself-execu) related to the service simulator before, and know that it has/had a severe bug: I have worked around this by defining the `get_welcome_response()` functions for their given intents first in the code.
5. I have followed the guidelines when defining invocation names for skills: english words, no proper nouns, 1-3 words, between 2-50 characters, etc

I have been trying to rack my brain around this issue for awhile — why Alexa can register my simpler skill but not my more complicated skill when there isn't anything substantial that differentiates them from one another — and know that the issue lies somewhere in the interaction model but it's not obvious to me where exactly it lies. For good measure, here is the interaction model for both skills:

**For simple test skill**:

*Intent schema:*

```
{
  "intents": [
    {
      "intent": "Morning"
   }
  ]
}
```

*associated utterance(s):*

```
Morning good morning
```

**For more complicated skill**:

*Intent schema:*

```
   {
         "intents": [
             {
             "intent": "Welcome"
             },
           {
             "intent": "Validate",
             "slots": [
               {
                 "name": "username",
                 "type": "LIST_OF_NAMES"
               },
               {
                 "name": "password",
                 "type": "AMAZON.NUMBER"
               }
             ]
           },
           { 
             "intent": "Report"
           }
         ]
      }
```

*associated utterance(s):*

```
Welcome good morning
Validate {username} and {password}
Report generate my report
```

Comment: What do your lambda log files say?

Comment: @JosephJaquinta for which case? When I configure the test environment for both an Alexa Start Session & an intent request for `Welcome`, neither set of logs seem particularly helpful: when the field for new session is flagged as `True` I get a null output with lambda logs that just give me the `RequestID`, `applicationID` and `sessionID`. I've tried inserting print statements into the code to see what's going on but that also hasn't been helpful